# llamado webapi enviando archivos de input type="file"

Tags: javascript, asp.net-web-api, mvc

Buenas tardes,

tengo el siguiente bloque de codigo:

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("Upload", "Orders", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
    {
      <input type="file" name="attach" id="attach" multiple />
      <input id="btnAttach" value="Upload" />
    }
```

y quiero que en ves de usar el html.beginform usar un $ajax para consumirlo, mi pregunta es como creo la data con base en los archivos que seleccione en mi input id=attach para consumir mi servicio web

```
$("$btnAttach").on("click", function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/order/Upload/",
            type: "POST",
            data: /* form data here */,
            success: SuccessCallback,
            error: FailureCallback
        });
    });
```

ya que con el primer metodo me da mucho problema en devolver una respuesta aprobiada al html para ser procesada

Answer (score 0):

Recomendaria le des uan mirada

[[ASP.NET Web API] Subiendo archivo con jQuery y Web API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/dn593719.aspx)

observaras que usa

```
    var files = $("#inputFile").get(0).files;
    var data = new FormData();
    for (i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        data.append("file" + i, files[i]);
    }
```

para armar el `data` que envia en el `$.ajax`, para lograrlo usa el objeto `FormData`

[Using FormData Objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects)